# How to use existing pod file in to the iOS(projectname.xcworkspace)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods

I, like to add the existing pod file in to existing xcode project in iOS.

Comment: you have a podspec of exixting project

Comment: @barani have u got solutions for it?

Comment: have u applied the given solution on my post?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the following steps to use existing pod file in your existing project :

- Copy that pod file, Go on your project path and paste on there.
- Now Open **terminal** type following command :

  ../..> **cd projectpath**
- Type **pod install**
- It will install all pod stacks which you mentioned in your pod file in your existing given destination project **OR** if you already fire above command then type **pod update**.
- Now go on your project path and see projectname.xcworkspace file. Open it and enjoy your coding with using pods.

**Note** : During Firing above command, xcode must be quite means not running on that time.